# Grafana + Prometheus monitoring using complex metrics with JSON parsing etc. - best practices

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have done setting up my Grafana and Prometheus servers, learned how to do a simple 'up' monitoring (whether host alive and responses on metrics_path or not).
And now I want to have some more Grafana panels describing entities that need JSON parsing and possibly some more difficult logic.
For example, I want to be able to poll my_cool_service/api/metrics/last_download_timestamp, parse a response, and print the resulting timestamp in a specific format.
Are there any best practices to achieve so?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve? showing the time when the last download happened?

Comment: Jens, not only that. First of all, I want to process JSON responses before printing them out as Grafana metrics. It's not that important how.